# Unity3d редактирование Scene'ы

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только начинаю осваивать Unity, скачал готовую карту из Asset Store, но почему-то не могу её редактировать нормальным образом из-за этих шаров на скрине, подскажите, что это такое, прокопался больше часа так и не поняв что это. Загуглить соответственно не смог по этой же причине.

Comment: Боюсь никто этого не сможет сказать ибо для этого нужно самим качать сцену и разбираться.....и непонятно что значит `не могу её редактировать нормальным образом`.......нормальным это каким?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский После запуска сцены шаров нет, так же я не могу их выделить мышкой, к примеру как видно на скрине, возле шаров есть дыра, на ней просто пустота и нет никаких коллайдеров, но при этом никакой объект (c Rigid body) не может выйти за их пределы.

Comment: Возможно в каком-либо скрипте рисуется что-то через `DrawGizmos` или в подобном методе..можно искать там, а может они а иерархии сцены где-то глубоко и на сцене включаются в определенный момент ......в любом случае это всё гадание на кофейной гуще.....без заглядывания внутрь этого самого ассета ничего сказать нельзя абсолютно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по картинке очень похоже на [LightProbe](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/LightProbes.html). То что туда пройти нельзя скорей всего связано с каким нибудь rigidbody по пути до этих шаров.